# Is it possible to get "ReTracing mapping" and "Native debug symbols" from .Net MAUI

Tags: google-play-console, visual-studio-2022, .net-maui

Is it possible to get "Native debug symbols" and "ReTrace mapping file" from a .Net MAUI project in VS 2022 pre. Trying to deploy an app to Google Play store for internal testning and the Google Play console suggests that I upload those files. Don't know where to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you face the error like 'you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug'? If so, please ignore the error now. Xamarin.Android doesn't have a solution for the native code yet, native debug symbols may not be supported for now.

Xamarin.Android does not generate native debugging symbols, please ignore the warning of the google play store. If you want to collect crash report in Xamarin project, you could use MS AppCenter to catch and report and app crashes.

Comment: Yes thats the message I am getting. Thank you! Ill ignore it for now.

Comment: Is this still correct? No way to debug when pushed to the store?